# C# LINQ Filter deep nested list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I've a structure based of list containing other list. I need to filter the list based on the value of a property based in the deepest part of the list.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
queryable = queryable
    .Include(x => x.Carriers)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.CarrierActions)
    .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Action)
    .ThenInclude(ac => ac.ActionFacts);

queryable = queryable
    .Where(x => x.Carriers.Any(
        carriers => carriers.CarrierActions.Any(
            carrieractions =>
                carrieractions.Action.ActionTypeId ==
                ActionTypeEnum.DosemeterCalculateDeepDose)));
```

I join the needed tables, then I filter them based on the ActionTypeId based 3 levels below the top list.

First off all, is it possible to do this in 1 step ( include the filtering with the joins ), second of all, the second part is not working as my list gets empty, but I'm certain that actions with that type get values.

Using .NET Core 2.0.3 btw!

Comment: What do you mean by "one step"? A single line? Be aware that any modification to that code may 1. make it harder to understand - it´s pretty straightforwards IMHO - and 2. and even worse it won´t make any difference as it surely will execute the same loops internally.

Comment: If you have backward navigation properties and list of Actions, then you could do something like `db.Actions.Where(x=>x.ActionTypeId==ActionTypeEnum.DosemeterCalculateDeepDose).Select(x=>x.CarrierAction.Carrier).Distinct()`

Comment: @HimBromBeere by 1 step I indeed ment the "Includes" combined with the filtering.

Comment: @GorRustamyan my db query is as follow: `var queryable = dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<IDosimetryDbContext>().Groups.AsQueryable();`. The thing is, I only need the actions when a certain filter is set to true in my request, so the Includes are executed later on. I need the groups, the carriers of that group & the actions, I don't think backward nav is possible here.

Comment: One thing, remember that you dont need all the includes if you dont need the entity as part of the result. With this I mean, you can filter in your 3rd level, but if you only want the 1st one as result, no need for the other 2 includes

Comment: @dariogriffo thanks for the info, but I need details on all 3 levels !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first part, you can do this

```
queryable = queryable
    .Include(x => x.Carriers)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.CarrierActions)
    .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Action)
    .ThenInclude(ac => ac.ActionFacts)
    .Where(x => x.Carriers.Any(
        carriers => carriers.CarrierActions.Any(
            carrieractions =>
                carrieractions.Action.ActionTypeId ==
                ActionTypeEnum.DosemeterCalculateDeepDose)))
```

To your second part, it should be working, id check your data, as this is pretty straight forward

Comment: Thanks first part worked, double checking all the data now and saw a link was missing. CarrierActions was empty ( I gave a refrence to the object instead of the carrier id to an action so for some reason the link was not made ? )

Comment: The reference should have worked, however i cant be sure without seeing the code, maybe debug that bit fo your code and check the db

Comment: Will do ! The persisting part isn't written by me so I'll check that out with my colleague. Thanks !