# c# - find a string from a nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following nested structure.

`List<SomeType>` which has another list of `List<AnotherType>` which internally has an `array of strings users`.

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }

    public List<AnotherType> AnotherType { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherType
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string[] Users { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I want to search for a value in the array of string `Users`. How can I do that.

Comment: gotta show SomeType and AnotherType before we can answer

Comment: Show us the code you have already tried and explain how it fails so we can advise how to fix code.

Comment: "Search for a value in the array of string Users" of which list or object(s)? Show us the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
var query = SomeTypeList
    .Where(sometype => sometype.AnotherType.Any(
        anothertype => anothertype.Users.Any(
             user => user.Contains("user to search for"))))
```

Looks like a duplicate: [stackoverflow: C# LINQ Filter deep nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809138/c-sharp-linq-filter-deep-nested-list)